# Up/down arrow on QTable View header for ascending/descending order

Tags: macos, qt

Is there any way in Qt to put up/down arrow on table view column header to sort in ascending/descending order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function to enable table's sorting:

```
QTableView::setSortingEnabled()
```

Setting 'true' will put an arrow on the header as soon as you click on it.

Comment: can  we style this arrow?

Comment: @SahilJain, I believe, yes. Please refer to this link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview

Comment: Thanks i made it work somehow but the size of image is not adjustable and very small.Do you have an idea about?

Comment: The arrow appears only after clicking on the header cell, which increases the width of the header cell and can mess up formatting - is there any way to have the arrow already there on first table display?

Comment: @Nostradamus, maybe calling `QTableView::sortByColumn()` will make that column sorted with the arrow on the header?